# Formula to find top 25 from the data set

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I've the following data and 10 more columns: What's the best formula to pull top 20 or top 25 of x and y combined? Should I go Index Match. If it's a macro, I'll have to write the code. I would prefer formula over code. Any suggestion?

```
    100   x
     50   y
     6    z
     89   x
     5    x
     24   y
```

Comment: What would be wrong with creating a column which contains the sum of `x` and `y` and sorting on that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by combined?

Comment: Where is the data and can't visualize `100 x 50 y 6 z 89 x 5 x 24 y`, can you decrypt it so we understand?

Comment: Tim, I can't do sum of it. I need it separate in my results

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you are looking for a pseudo-LARGEIF formula. This can be based on the [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) and the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) as a standard (*non-array*) formuala.

[image: LARGE IF formula]

The formulas in D3:F3 are,

```
=LARGE(INDEX(($A$2:$A$99)*(($B$2:$B$99="x")+($B$2:$B$99="y")), , ), ROW(1:1))    ◄ LARGEIF column B is x or y
=LARGE(INDEX(($A$2:$A$99)*($B$2:$B$99=$E$2), , ), ROW(1:1))    ◄ LARGEIF column B is x
=LARGE(INDEX(($A$2:$A$99)*($B$2:$B$99="y"), , ), ROW(1:1))     ◄ LARGEIF column B is y
```

If you have a lot of choices, you can use an *array of constants* to match. D3 could also be,

```
=LARGE(INDEX(($A$2:$A$99)*($B$2:$B$99={"x","y"}), , ), ROW(1:1))    ◄ LARGEIF column B is x or y
```

Fill down as necessary. These are standard formula and do not require CSE.

Comment: Since I can't split columns for x and y, I guess I will try using 
=LARGE(INDEX(($A$2:$A$99)*($B$2:$B$99={"x","y"}), , ), ROW(1:1))    ◄ LARGEIF column B is x or y

Comment: So the formulae worked and pulled the $ values for all. I tried using the same formula to pull another column that had all text and that didn't work. Any specific reason you can think of?

Comment: From your description *pull top 20 or top 25* I have retrieved the numerically largest with [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db). Text values do not have a numerically *large* value so it would appear that some other method would have to be used.

Comment: I've used Index, Small before to pull text fields and it has pulled it in. Seems like Large wouldn't pull and small would?

Comment: If you used the [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) successfully, then the SMALL was probably acting on the *row to return* which is a number, not the text. That sounds like you want the closest to the top of the list, not the numerically largest value. If you used LARGE in the same ways, you would be getting records starting from the bottom of the list. It sounds like you need to provide some sample data together with the expected results. Perhaps close this off with an accepted answer and start fresh.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221827/formula-to-pull-all-data-for-top-25 Added another question. Probably that might help ?