# Formula to pull all data for Top 25

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I've following data set and I've used Index- Large function

```
=LARGE(INDEX(($A$2:$A$99)*($B$2:$B$99={"x","y"}), , ), ROW(1:1))
```

... to find out Top 25 of x and y combined. How would I pull the Column that has listed fruits? I can't use Large since it's for Numbers only. I've 20 more columns that have text only. Any thoughts?

```
apple        100    x  
banana        50    y  
grapes         6    z  
watermelon    89    x  
cantaloupe     5    x  
orange        24    y
```

Comment: =INDEX(Data!$B$2:$B$74,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(Data!$B$2:$B$74,Data!$B$2:$B$74)),COUNTIF(Data!$B$2:$B$74,Data!$B$2:$B$74),0))  I tried using this with CSE (array formula) and does return the correct value but then returns the same when I drag it down the row.

Comment: Please define *Top 25*. Do you mean the first 25 in the list that have *x* or *y*? Do you mean the matching text from the top 25 numbers? As it sits, the term *Top 25* is simply too ambiguous to offer a solution.

Comment: Matching text from the top 25 numbers. Can't use lookups since numbers might be same.. So for x & y from above sample, I would get 
Apple  , Watermelon, Banana, Orange, Grapes

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the formula you provided for the correct columns first.

```
=LARGE(INDEX(($B$2:$B$99)*($C$2:$C$99={"x","y"}), , ), ROW(1:1))
```

When that is done, it can be used as matching criteria in a larger formula that also matches column C for *x, y*.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$99, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+(($C$2:$C$99<>{"x","y"})+($B$2:$B$99<>LARGE(INDEX(($B$2:$B$99)*($C$2:$C$99={"x","y"}), , ), ROW(1:1))))*1E+99, , ))), "")
```

In the sample image below, that formula would go into E4. Fill both right and down as necessary.

[image: Top 25 text listings sorted numerically]

If the values in the *nmbr* column may be duplicated (while still matching {x, y}) then one formula cannot be used for the entire lookup table. Use the following in F4.

```
=LARGE(INDEX(($B$2:$B$99)*($C$2:$C$99={"x","y"}), , ), ROW(1:1))
```

E4 would be,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$99, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+(($C$2:$C$99<>{"x","y"})+($B$2:$B$99<>LARGE(INDEX(($B$2:$B$99)*($C$2:$C$99={"x","y"}), , ), ROW(1:1))))*1E+99, , ), COUNTIF($F$4:$F4, $F4))), "")
```

Copy and paste E4 to G4 then select E4:G4 and fill down.

[image: Top 25 text listings sorted numerically with duplicates]

Note that when transcribing the formula for your own use, ROW(1:98) is the *position within* A2:A99, not the actual row on the worksheet.

Comment: That works as long as there aren't duplicate numbers within the x and y values, e.g. if B3 is changed to 89 then although 89 will be listed twice, banana is shown against both, rather than `banana` and `watermelon`

Comment: @barryhoudini - Good point. Bringing a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) into the mix to adjust the *k* of SMALL (replacing MIN)  could resolve that.

Comment: @DK - Honestly, I did not photoshop that image. Read my narrative thoroughly.

Comment: Works fine for me,. Adjusted the Row () formula and good to go. thanks for your help!!