# Vlookup/Index Function Trouble

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to pull the latest date from a range.  That range must match the customer name and whether its live or closed.

Column L (Live Date) lists all the dates.
Column A (HQ Name) lists names of all the customers which can have multiple lines with the same customer name.
Column C (Status) lists the status of the customer (Live, Closed, other).
I have the customer name I am trying to match it to in cell B1.

This is the closest I can get.

=index(Table_owssvr_1[Live Date],MATCH(B1,Table_owssvr_1[HQ Name],0))

That will return the first date for the customer in the date range.

Been struggling on this for hours and cannot figure out the next step.  Please help!

Comment: Hi whats the value in B1 your trying to match it to? if I have it correct there are duplicates in the customer column with dates say 1sy,2nd,3rd etc and you want to return the most recent date for customer somewhere? AND concat the status?

Comment: It sounds like you need a filtered lookup to return more than one row of data. See if [Formula to pull all data for Top 25](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221827/formula-to-pull-all-data-for-top-25/30222580#30222580) is appropriate.

Comment: The value in B1 is on a different worksheet and it is the exact customer name.  I am matching that with Column A in the other worksheet which has the table with all the information on it (column A, C and L).

Comment: Yes Jeeped, that does sound like something I need.  I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: Yes there are duplicate customers in the customer column and they have different (sometimes the same) live dates.  I am trying to find the one with the latest date.

Comment: So the formula to get the last date makes sense.  I am thinking something like this `={LARGE(IF(A:A=B1,1,0)*IF(ISNUMBER(L:L),L:L,0),1)}`  But I am confused about what you want done with the status...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the data is setup as this dummy example data:

```
A        B      C       D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
-----------------------------------------------------------------
HQ Name (input) Status                                  Live Date
James           Closed                                  5/13/2015
Bill            Other                                   5/13/2015
Amy             Closed                                  5/14/2015
Amy             Closed                                  5/14/2015
Bill            Live                                    5/15/2015
James           Closed                                  5/16/2015
Bill            Live                                    5/16/2015
Bill            Live                                    5/17/2015
James           Other                                   5/17/2015
Amy             Live                                    5/18/2015
```

And the desired output for each result would be:

1. Amy -> 5/18/2015
2. James -> 5/17/2015
3. Bill -> 5/17/2015

That can be accomplished by using an array formula:

```
=LARGE(IF(A:A=B1,1,0)*IF(ISNUMBER(L:L),L:L,0),1)
```

*Array formulas are entered with* <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Which would return for example:

```
A        B              C       D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
HQ Name  Amy            Status                                  Live Date
James    5/18/2015      Closed                                  5/13/2015
Bill                    Other                                   5/13/2015
Amy                     Closed                                  5/14/2015
Amy                     Closed                                  5/14/2015
Bill                    Live                                    5/15/2015
James                   Closed                                  5/16/2015
Bill                    Live                                    5/16/2015
Bill                    Live                                    5/17/2015
James                   Other                                   5/17/2015
Amy                     Live                                    5/18/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://wikisend.com/download/600864/Examp.xlsx) and let me know how far off it is?

very simple example but you could concat the two result columns and there's your answer, this will always work providing you sort the dataset by live date

Comment: Another detail I probably should have mentioned.  This table is essentially a web query and I will be refreshing the info everyday so I wont be doing any sorting.